# How to pass list in @Input using Angular5?

Tags: javascript, angular

I wanted to know how to pass the list through the input. I have in parent component:

```
list: Hero[] = [{Id: 2, Name: "Sll"}, {Id: 3, Name: "Sldsadasd"}]
```

and in html:

```
<app-add-hero list="{{list}}" hero={{hero}}></app-add-hero>
```

and in child component

```
@Input() list : Hero[];
hero : Hero;
constructor() { }
printHero(): void{
    console.log(this.list[1]);
}
```

but console print "o"

Comment: Use property binding `[list]="list"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the interpolation which is not necessary,

```
<app-add-hero [list]="list"></app-add-hero>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on the top of Sajeetharan's answer,

The Interpolation Syntax(`{{...}}`), that you've used here:

```
<app-add-hero list="{{list}}" hero={{hero}}></app-add-hero>
```

is generally for strings, unless you've used it in conjunction with the `async` and `json` pipes. So this syntax is generally used for passing `string` values as `@Input` properties to components.

So if in your ChildComponent, `list` was of type `string`:

```
@Input() list : string;
```

then doing `<app-add-hero list="{{list}}" ...` would have worked.

But since it is not, you'll have to use the Property Binding Syntax(`[nameOfTheInputProperty]="nameOfTheComponentPropertyToAssignFrom"`), which in your case, would be:

```
<app-add-hero list="{{list}}"></app-add-hero>
```

Also, since `hero` is not an `@Input` property defined on your Child Component, you can't use it in your Parent Component Template.